# How can I add jar files to the CLASSPATH in Linux?

Tags: java, classpath, xalan

I am pretty new with this, I need to install an application (XSLTC) on a Linux machine (I am using PuTTy).
I read the instructions [here](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html). I quote:

> To use XSLTC, simply put xalan.jar, serializer.jar, xml-apis.jar, and xercesImpl.jar on your classpath

How do I do add jar files to the classpath?

Comment: did you try putting the jars under $HOME/bin? I think that is the easiest.

Answer (score 10):

First thing to note - you're not using "Putty" to set the CLASSPATH, you're using the 'shell' that you login to, using Putty as your SSH client.

Depending on your shell, there are different ways to set your classpath -

**Bash** (or compatible shells

```
export CLASSPATH=/full/path/to/xalan.jar:/full/path/to/serializer.jar:/full/path/to/xml-apis.jar:/full/path/to/xercesImpl.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

**C Shell** (or compatible shells)

```
setenv CLASSPATH /full/path/to/xalan.jar:/full/path/to/serializer.jar:/full/path/to/xml-apis.jar:/full/path/to/xercesImpl.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: do I need to restart something after I do that?

Comment: No, just run your application.

Comment: You can drop the `export`; There is no need to create this as an environment variable.  You either pass values via the environment, or as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Define an environment variable in your putty session for `CLASSPATH` with the path of required jars. If you are using bash shell in putty then `export CLASSPATH=<Jar Path>:$CLASSPATH` will help. Use `java -cp .:$CLASSPATH ...` for including your `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: first I need to do this: export CLASSPATH=:$CLASSPATH, and then: "java -cp .:$CLASSPATH ..."? what should appear instead of the dots?

Comment: An example could be java -cp .:$CLASSPATH org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline.Transform
     hamlet.xml hamlet

Comment: Instead of the dots, you need a public class and method from one of the containers (directories, jars) that you passed on with the `-cp` option to `java`.